# Why cv.tree() can't find this object when called from inside a function?

Tags: r, scope

I seem to have a namespace or scope issue when calling cv.tree() inside a function:

```
library(tree)
library(ISLR)
Carseats$High = ifelse(Sales <= 8, "No", "Yes")

mytreecv = function(formula, mydata)
{
  set.seed(2)
  tree.carseats = tree(formula, mydata)
  cv.carseats = cv.tree(tree.carseats, FUN=prune.misclass)
}
```

When I run mytreecv() I get this error:

```
> mytreecv(High ~ . - Sales, Carseats)
Error in is.data.frame(data) (from #5) : object 'mydata' not found
```

The cv.tree() call to model.frame(object) fails. The same function code works when I call each line from the R prompt.

Comment: I have the same problem with cv.tree() being called inside a function, I've tried just about everything I can think of, did you ever solve it?

Comment: Of course right after I posted I found the answer somewhere else...I'll put it in answers.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why this happens but it can be fixed by creating a tree with the argument model = T. Using the example above:

```
mytreecv = function(formula, mydata)
{
  set.seed(2)
  tree.carseats = tree(formula, mydata, model = T)
  cv.carseats = cv.tree(tree.carseats, FUN=prune.misclass)
}
```

Answer found here: http://florence.acadiau.ca/collab/hugh_public/index.php?title=R:putting_cv.tree_inside_a_function&redirect=no